# How to do a popup coming from right

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

I've been trying to create a modal popup for several days now but I can't find any solution that really works.
I would like the modal popup to come from the right like a page in the settings on iOS without blocking the scroll. I specify "without blocking the scroll" because I already tried with a modal popup in absolute or fixed position but it doesn't have the right height.
For those who don't see what I would like to achieve, here is an image that might help you understand:

[image: Image that can help]

Thanks to all those who will take the time to answer me.
Sorry I can't give you a piece of code, but I'm stuck.

Comment: As you have already tried some stuff please could you show us it as a starting point. Even just the code that structures the actual page would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

see this:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let aside = document.querySelector("aside");

btn.onclick = function () {
    aside.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #0af;
}
#btn {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 5px;
}
#btn span {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}
aside {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    right: -60vw; /* - width */
    width: 60vw;
    background-color: #0df;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.active {
    right: 0 !important;
}
aside ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
aside ul li:hover {
    background-color: #86efff;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        logo
    </div>
    <div id="btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</header>
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
</aside>
<div class="content">
    <h1>This Is content</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, eaque? Blanditiis eligendi reprehenderit nihil? Deleniti iusto saepe ullam incidunt! Ipsum quibusdam soluta accusantium debitis ad voluptatum doloremque ratione, nihil amet?
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quisquam, delectus quasi repellat at omnis doloribus nisi quod aperiam consequuntur, id adipisci perspiciatis? Laudantium labore dignissimos dolore quis voluptate? Aliquid, maxime!
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates quos fugit laboriosam, dolorem soluta in et? Libero repellendus necessitatibus quo hic est voluptate odit dolore tempore quasi. Fugit, culpa sint?
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it does not answer my problem because if the total height of all the links exceeds the height of the window, I will not be able to scroll the whole window (no need to tell me to put "overflow-y: scroll" on the menu.

Thanks again for your answer